# react-select value container not clickable to close menu list?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

This is my component.

```
components={{
          ValueContainer: ({ children, ...props }) => {
            const groupedOptions = groupBy(selectedOptions, 'groupName')
            const firstGroupName = Object.keys(groupedOptions)[0]

            if (firstGroupName === undefined)
              return (
                <Placeholder {...props} onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}>
                  Select one or more accounts
                  {children}
                </Placeholder>
              )

            const firstGroupAccounts = groupedOptions[firstGroupName]
              .flatMap((acc) => acc.accounts)
              .map((acc) => ({
                id: acc.id,
                name: acc.name,
                avatar: acc.avatar,
                platform: acc.platform as PlatformName,
                color: acc.color,
              }))

            return (
              <components.ValueContainer {...props}>
                <OptionRow onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}>
                  <AvatarGroupNew
                    accounts={firstGroupAccounts}
                    labelText={firstGroupName}
                    size={24}
                  />
                </OptionRow>
              </components.ValueContainer>
            )
          }
```

It can be closed clicking the icon of `AvatarGroupNew` but not the entire menu. I expect the stopPropagation would work on OptionRow but it doesn't seems to have any effect.

I've also tried to manually trigger using menuIsOpen but no luck.

I can't catch what's wrong here. Thanks!